# socket connect with timeout hangs if not connected to a network

Tags: c, sockets

The following routine will timeout if a non-existant ip address is given, which is great.  However, if the linux system (which it is running on) is not connected to any network on either eth0 or wlan0 then it hangs.  Even if a network is connected to eth0 again, still no response.  Is there a way to get the timeout to apply even if not connected to a network?  Alternatively, is there a check that can be done before hand that will determine if a connection to a network exists? Thanks.

```
int connect_to_host()
{

    u_short port;                /* user specified port number */
    char *addr;                  /* will be a pointer to the address */
    struct sockaddr_in address;  /* the libc network address data structure */
    short int sock = -1;         /* file descriptor for the network socket */
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int connected = 0;

    port = 22;
    addr = "192.168.2.5";

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr); /* assign the address */
    address.sin_port = htons(port);            /* translate int2port num */

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec = 3;             /* 10 second timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    if (select(sock + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv) == 1)
    {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;

        getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        if (so_error == 0) {
            printf("%s:%d is open\n", addr, port);
        connected = 1;
        }
    }

    close(sock);
    return connected;

}
```

Comment: tv.tv_sec = 3;  /* 10 second timeout */     <--- heh

Comment: @EJP thank you for your question.  Normally narrowing down the error is something I would do automatically, this was my first error.  However, the real bonehead error was not realizing that I was trying to run the executable over a network filesystem.  When I disconnected from the network to test it out, well what do you know it wasn't there anymore to execute.  Funny the response was just to hang.  Anyway, I copied the executable to /tmp, then disconnected, then executed and it works fine. :)